# Create a dynamic preferences panel using Firefox's Add-on SDK

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I've created a simple Firefox add-on where each time the user selects some text on a page, a small popup with the user's search engines appears, which you can then click to search the web. It mimics plugins such as [this one](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/selected-search/) or FastestFox's popup panel.

The add-on uses all of the user's search engines by default, but **I want to let the user hide certain engines** from my panel, **without affecting the browser's search engines manager**. Using the SDK's `simple-prefs`, I can create settings in `packages.json`: int values, buttons (controls), checkboxes, dropdown menus, etc. However, **search engines are different for each user and dynamic** (they can be added or removed from the browser).

I added a button to my add-on's preferences menu:

[image: Example of a simple-prefs button that does *something*]

This button should open **some window that shows all search engines** and a **checkbox behind each of them** (to enable/disable them in my popup). I think I could save these extra settings using `simple-storage`. But now I don't know how to proceed from here.

This is what Adblock does:

[image: Adblock's simple-prefs + button for extra settings window]

I've also seen at least one add-on place all its settings in an HTML page.

**Actual questions:** Should I create a window for this? (What is the API I should use for that?) Or is it better to generate a webpage and handle everything through HTML and JavaScript? (Seems much harder!)

This is the first add-on I try developing for Firefox and I'm having a hard time finding info on the web. Everything in my add-on comes from the High-Level APIs of the [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/Add-ons/SDK) (No overlay extensions. No XUL.) Actually, having all these options confuses me.

Comment: Is your code on github? This is very easy I can show you how to do it. On github i can give you a pull request.

Comment: My code is currently in my machine only. I intend to make it available later on through Mozilla's add-on page and github. But thanks for being willing to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I didn't want to mix the Add-on SDK (high level modules) with XUL extension development, I ended up creating a function that is triggered when the "Select from available search engines" button is clicked. This function creates an HTML panel (sdk/panel) that is then populated with the available search engines, placing a checkbox behind each one. Some events are also set so that, when a checkbox is clicked, the engine's status (enabled/disabled) is saved using the sdk/simple-storage module.

This is the code for the button in the add-on options (in package.json):

```
...
"preferences": [
{
    "name": "selectEnginesButton",
    "title": "Select from available search engines",
    "type": "control",
    "description": "Enable/disable the search engines that show on the popup panel.",
    "label": "Select"
},
...
```

Then, in main.js:

```
var simplePrefs = require('sdk/simple-prefs');
var simpleStorage = require("sdk/simple-storage");

// ...some code for other things here...

if (!simpleStorage.storage.searchEngines) {
    simpleStorage.storage.searchEngines = {};
}

simplePrefs.on("selectEnginesButton", function() {
    createSettingsPanel();
});

function createSettingsPanel()
{
    var visibleEngines = searchService.getVisibleEngines({});
    var engines = visibleEngines.filter(function(engine) { return !engine.hidden; });

    // Create simple objects with engine information to pass to the panel's content script
    // This is because only main.js can work with the search engine objects themselves
    // i.e. the ones in "engines"
    var engineObjects = engines.map(function(engine) {
        var engineObject = {};
        engineObject.name = engine.name;
        engineObject.iconSpec = (engine.iconURI != null ? engine.iconURI.spec : null);
        engineObject.active = isEngineActive(engine);
        return engineObject;
    });

    var pan = panel.Panel({
        contentURL: data.url("engine-settings.html"),
        contentScriptFile: data.url("engine-settings.js"),
        width: 400,
        height: 225
    });

    pan.port.emit('setupPanel', engineObjects);
    pan.port.on("onSearchEngineToggle", onSearchEngineToggle);

    pan.show();
}

function onSearchEngineToggle(engine)
{
    simpleStorage.storage.searchEngines[engine.name] = engine.active;
}

function isEngineActive(engine)
{
    return simpleStorage.storage.searchEngines[engine.name];
}
```

Finally, the panel's HTML (engine-settings.html):

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- some css and other stuff -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="title">Select what search engines are shown on the popup panel:</div>
    <div id="engines"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

...and the panel's JavaScript (engine-settings.js):

```
self.port.on('setupPanel', setupPanel);
self.port.on('logInnerHTML', logInnerHTML);

function setupPanel(engines)
{
    engines.forEach(addEngineToLayout);
}

function addEngineToLayout(engine)
{
    // WARNING: this might not be the best way to populate HTML from js. I'm certainly no expert here :)

    var element = document.createElement("div");
    var description = document.createTextNode(engine.name);
    var checkbox = document.createElement("input");

    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.value = engine.name;
    checkbox.checked = engine.active;

    element.appendChild(checkbox);

    var icon = document.createElement("img");
    // default.png is a png of mine, in case an engine has no icon
    icon.setAttribute("src", (engine.iconSpec != null ? engine.iconSpec : "default.png"));
    element.appendChild(document.createElement("span"));
    element.appendChild(icon);

    element.appendChild(document.createElement("span"));
    element.appendChild(description);

    document.getElementById('engines').appendChild(element);

    checkbox.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
        engine.active = !engine.active;
        self.port.emit('onSearchEngineToggle', engine);
    });
}
```

Of course, this is not a perfect solution, but you get a simple panel that shows on top of the other settings when you click the button in the add-on preferences. It disappears when you press outside of it.

Note that this code has engines disabled by default, as they will not be present in `simpleStorage.storage.searchEngines`. You can change this by doing this in `isEngineActive`:

```
function isEngineActive(engine)
{
    if (!simpleStorage.storage.searchEngines.hasOwnProperty(engine.name)) {
        simpleStorage.storage.searchEngines[engine.name] = true;
    }
    return simpleStorage.storage.searchEngines[engine.name];
}
```

When engines are removed from the browser, they'll still be forever present in `simpleStorage.storage.searchEngines`. You can easily fix this by going through everything in there when your `main.js` runs and removing engines that don't exist anymore.

I hope this helps someone! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make your control button have this `oncommand` function:

```
<setting title="Do Something" type="control">
  <button id="myaddon-button" label="Click Me" oncommand="Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').BrowserSearch.searchBar.openManager(event)"/>
</setting>
```

Comment: I have no XML-type files in my add-on. Is that XUL? I define my preferences in package.json, where the button is:

`"name": "selectEnginesButton",
"type": "control",
(...)`

I managed to get your code working in my case by doing this in main.js:

`prefs.on("selectEnginesButton", function() {
 Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').BrowserSearch.searchBar.openManager();
});`

Unfortunately, this is not what I want, as I don't want the user to add/remove search engines with my add-on; I simply want to let him/her select which of the installed engines to show in the popup.

Comment: I re-wrote my question a bit to avoid further confusion. Sorry if it was not clear!

Comment: Hm im not too familiar with `package.json` of addon-sdk, but try adding `"command":"the code i have above in oncommand"`.

Comment: If you would like to make a window like AdBlock yes you have to create a `blah.xul` and then on click of the button you have to do `Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser'). openDialog("chrome://browser/content/search/engineManager.xul",
 "_blank", "chrome,dialog,modal,centerscreen,resizable");`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) I have read that mixing the new SDK and XUL might complicate things for me (packaging, learning XUL, etc) and I'm trying to keep my add-on simple, so I think I'll wait for some more options if anyone else has suggestions. Otherwise I'll go with a HTML page (or panel) to choose the active engines. As for package.json, there is unfortunately no "command" documented, so it seems that it really has to be done like I did, using `prefs.on("buttonName", ...)`.